# Print tables using python camelot library to used to extract tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-camelot

Is there a way to get the sdout of the extracted tables of the PDFs to print in the terminal? Example:

```
import camelot

tables = camelot.read_pdf('List.pdf')
tables.export('newpdf.json', f='json')

for row in tables[0]  #trying to print table...
    print (row)
```

Comment: Did you try:
    `for table in tables:`
        `print(table)`

Comment: Yeah, nothing relevant comes out.

Comment: I recommend you to check the `len(tables)` first. It seems like no tables are detected?! Tweak the params accordingly to suit your PDF file and recheck the length.

Comment: No, the tables are detected but there's no stdout. There's a json file or csv file with the table content. variable: tables does not have stdout content